# How to use a vim list in a python command?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, vim, command-line

My vim list:

```
  let ListRange = []  
  let ListRange = ['2','3','hello']
```

I want to import the list in a python command:

```
exe "r!python -c \"import random ; print('\\n'.join(format(random.choice(ListRange)) for i in range(14)))\""
```

This gives an **error**:
*Traceback (most recent call last):*
  *File "", line 1, in 

  File "", line 1, in 

NameError: global name 'listrange' is not defined*

How can I use the vim list in above python command?

I know that it is possible to declare the list within the python command self, but I want to declare it from within vim environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `:execute`, you need to carefully distinguish between the *quoted parts*, which are evaluated by Python, and the unquoted parts, which are Vim expressions. Your mistake is that `ListRange` is a Vim variable, but you've included it in the quoted Python part.

To fix this, split the string into two parts, and insert the `ListRange` literally and unquoted, using Vim's `string()` to generate a text representation of the list:

```
exe "r!python -c \"import random ; print('\\n'.join(format(random.choice(" . string(ListRange) . ")) for i in range(14)))\""
```

You're lucky here that Vim's and Python's List formats are very similar; it only works because of this (for this particular input; more complex List contents may cause failures).

Comment: Glad I could help. That question was very clear and precise, and fortunately it had a simple solution!